# Как правильно вызвать метод onLoadMoreListener?

Tags: android, recyclerview, listener

Не знаю, как правильно обратиться к методу onLoadMoreLIstener в классе, чтобы подгружать дополнительные элементы RecyclerView сверху.

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://medium.com/@programmerasi/how-to-implement-load-more-in-recyclerview-3c6358297f4

Comment: У меня примерно так же и было реализовано, оно вылетает в onCreate на этом методе